# Vue.js 2.0: Modify object properties from method

Tags: javascript, object, vue.js, methods

I have an object with some blank properties in my component's data that I would like to modify with a method that is run on a click event on one of my listed elements. When I examine the click event in console, I get returned an object with `Getter & Setter` for all of the properties.

Here's my code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <li v-for="user in userList.users" :key="user.localized_name" @click="loadUser(user.name, user.id)>
            Click me!
        </li>
    </div>
</template>

....

data: function () {
    return {
        userList: [...]
        userSelected: {
            name: '',
            id: '',
        }
    }
}

methods: {
    loadUser (userName, userId) {
        Vue.set(this.userSelected, name, userName);
        Vue.set(this.userSelected, id, userId);
        console.log(this.userSelected)
    }
}
```

This last `console.log(this.userSelected)` shows me an array where every property is filled by `Getter & Setter` as I mentioned. What do I need to change here?

Comment: don't use `Vue.set` to update object properties, you could simply do : `this.userSelected.name=userName`

Comment: Try doing `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.userSelected))`, that might give you more accurate data.

Comment: In your `Vue.set` calls, `name` and `id` are undefined (you probably meant `'name'` and `'id'`. I'd be very surprised if you weren't seeing errors reported for this, eg _"Uncaught ReferenceError: name is not defined"_

Comment: Also, using `console.log` on Vue's reactive data properties is rarely useful due to their proxy-like nature. Use the Vue devtools browser extension instead.

Comment: @Dr_Derp This console.log gives me the information I was expecting. When I pass this data to another component as a prop, will I need to stringify the object in the new component for the same information?

Comment: No, you will not need to stringify your data if you use the right tools to view it

Comment: The only reason you are having issues is when you view this in the Developer Tools, the object will show you its state as it is at the time of viewing. But you don't want that-you want to see what the object looked like when you log it.

Answer (score 1):

Making this into an answer so that I can have better structuring.

When you run `console.log(someObject)` and you're using Chrome or similar browsers, the Developer Tools do not, as you would expect, make a copy of the object and print it (pass by value). Instead, the Tools hold onto a reference to that object

[Reference Vs Value](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/understanding-by-reference-vs-by-value-d49139beb1c4)

This means that if you have the following code:

```
const object = { foo: { foo2: 'bar' } };
console.log(object);
object.foo.foo2 = 'bar2';
console.log(object);
```

Both the first and second console.logs are exactly the same when viewed in the Developer Tools. This is because the reference they are pointing to is exactly the same.

[image: Chrome Dev Tools Showing Output]

However, if you run the object through JSON.stringify first, then this means you are no longer passing the object to console.log. Instead, a new string is created both times

```
const object = { foo: { foo2: 'bar' } };
console.log(JSON.stringify(object));
object.foo.foo2 = 'bar2';
console.log(JSON.stringify(object));
```

[image: Second Chrome Developer Tools showing example]

There are reasons the Developer Tools work this way, I'm sure, probably very good ones. I don't know what they are, maybe someone else who does can comment on that. Normally it's just a little thing you have to bear in mind that can trip you up.

So in answer to your question in the comments, you do NOT need to stringify your object to pass it to other components, and in fact should not, because it's going to make things more difficult. You just have to do it in this one case because Developer Tools are funny like that.